# How can I arrange items on RecyclerView based on condition?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to display items on `Recyclerview` if columns 3 select from back-end `RecyclerView` first three items on first row and four one in second row, if columns 4 first four item on first row and five in second row.

how can arrange above list in `RecyclerView`

```
   recyclerViewLineItem.setHasFixedSize(false);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerViewLineItem.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

[image]

Comment: You can use **[GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager)**

Comment: Try StaggerGridLayoutMAnager

Comment: but i want horizontal scroll

Answer (score 1):

Use `GridLayoutManager` class if number of columns are more than 1

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(activity, 2/*column count*/);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

& for horizontal scrolling, use this

```
new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1 /*column count*/, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
```

Comment: what about `RecyclerView` ?

Comment: Check answer again

Comment: @RahulChokshi you can use GridLayoutManager in RecyclerView (instead of using LinearLayoutManager)

Answer (score 1):

This is actually very easy. You need to use GridLayoutManager instead of the usual LinearLayoutManager.
Inside GridLayoutManager, you can choose how many columns you want depending upon the number of items. Let me show you:

```
int spanCount = 0 ; //This is the number of column you need, set to 0 at first
if(yourItemCount == 3){
spanCount = 3; //set to 3 columns
};
if(yourItemCount == 5){
spanCount = 4; //set to 4 columns, and the 5th item will be at the second row
}

//now pass the spanCount to the GridLayoutManager
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(activity, spanCount);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

Hope it helps.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing position from your adapter and in your activity/fragment you can create a method which display data according to the values passed.

```
    private void CheckColumn(RecyclerView recyclerView) {

    int count = recyclerView.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View view = recyclerView.getChildAt(i);

       // Your code to show grid items here
    }  

}
```